# Prevent server freeze by overload - linux

Tags: linux

Is there any application that prevents a linux server from freezing by cpu overload?
Sometimes, by mistake, someone overload it by executing different tasks in parallel and it freezes the machine what causes a reboot need.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the cpu available per user: take a look in `/etc/security/limits.conf` (read the comments in the file or use `man limits.conf`)

You can also launch `ulimit -a` to see what resource limits are in effect